# Designing a database for dynamic affiliate links

Tags: database, database-design

I am in the planning phase of building a site that depends on affiliate links. I'm having a hard time coming up with a good design because the affiliate links change based on different criteria:

- Product ID
- Affiliate ID
- User's location
- User's device

For example:

The link http://site.com/affiliate/11111/id/10000 is for the following criteria:

- Product 10's link is clicked
- User's country is US, UK, CA or AU
- They're using an Android device

For http://site.com/affiliate/11111/id/10001

- Product 10's link is clicked
- User's country is US, UK, CA or AU
- Using iOS device

For http://site.com/affiliate/11111/id/10002

- Product 10's link is clicked
- User's country is DE
- Using Android device

Basically, if any of those factors change, it could have a specific link for it. It's not consistent.

I'm probably going to use mod_rewrite to help focus on the queries to be something like:

http://mysite.com/outgoing/product-name/11111/android/us

This will be used to generate a query, but I don't know what I want to do for the database design so it's flexible and prevents having to manually inserting a link that matches every possible combination.

I was originally thinking of a single table like this:

- link_id - Auto_incremented PK
- affiliate_id
- country_code
- product_id
- affiliate_link

But to do the first example above for just one single product_id:

```
| link_id | affiliate_id | country_code |   device     | product_id |            affiliate_link                 |
+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|    1    |    11111     |      US      |   android    |     10     |  http://site.com/affiliate/11111/id/10000 |
+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|    2    |    11111     |      UK      |   android    |     10     |  http://site.com/affiliate/11111/id/10000 |
+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|    3    |    11111     |      CA      |   android    |     10     |  http://site.com/affiliate/11111/id/10000 |
+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|    4    |    11111     |      AU      |   android    |     10     |  http://site.com/affiliate/11111/id/10000 |
+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|    5    |    11111     |      US      |     iOS      |     10     |  http://site.com/affiliate/11111/id/10001 |
+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|    6    |    11111     |      UK      |     iOS      |     10     |  http://site.com/affiliate/11111/id/10001 |
+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|    7    |    11111     |      CA      |     iOS      |     10     |  http://site.com/affiliate/11111/id/10001 |
+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|    8    |    11111     |      AU      |     iOS      |     10     |  http://site.com/affiliate/11111/id/10001 |
+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|    9    |    11111     |      DE      |   android    |     10     |  http://site.com/affiliate/11111/id/10002 |
+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|    10   |    11111     |      DE      |     iOS      |     10     |  http://site.com/affiliate/11111/id/10003 |
```

See why I'm hesitant to do it this way?

It just seems so inefficient and complicated. There has to be a better way to do this, but I just can't think of it right now.

To make it more complicated, sometimes I'll get a link for "any country", but excluding the ones that already have a link.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: First of all, I think you can make affiliate_id, country_code, device,      product_id as Foreign Key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two different tables: one table stores the atomic data about each affiliate (id, product code, link) and one for the non-atomic data, the country code; this table would need only two columns which together create the unique, primary key - affiliate id + country code. This solution would prevent the needless repetition of data.